# Embedded google-map on a fullPage website

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, fullpage.js

I just embedded my google map to my website which uses a fullPage.js, but I have a small problem. When the mouse cursor/pointer is on the top of the map and when trying to zoom in/out it also moves to the next/previous page.
Image of the website with embedded map: `https://i.imgur.com/fjBC2my.png`

I really haven't tried anything because I am new to this world of programmers and I don't know from where to start so I can solve this issue of mine.
So I would really appreciate if you help me and give me some hints to make this possible

All I have done is disabling mouse scroll (moving only from the nav-bar or with keyboard arrows) but that is not a permanent solution.

This is my index.php: `https://pastebin.com/EThG2EG3`
And this is the fullPage.js that I am using with disabled mouse scroll (maybe it's not the latest version): `https://pastebin.com/sm14aAie`

What I am trying to accomplish is when the pointer is on the top of the map it should focus on the map and it should not move from page to page (this applies when in full screen of the map as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the **normalScrollElements** parameter in the Github documentation for the FullPage.js plugin. When you initialize the plugin in your javascript, try adding this param with the element id of your map.

Add ID for map in CSS:

```
<div class="section" id="section1">
    <div class="intro" id="gmap">
        <center>
            <?php require('lib/map.php'); ?>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add Javascript Parameter:

```
var myFullpage = new fullpage ('#fullpage',
{
    sectionsColor: ['red', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'red'],
    anchors: ['home', 'locations', 'about', 'contact'],
    menu: '#menu',
    slidesNavigation: true,
    normalScrollElements: '#gmap',
    // lazyLoad: true,
});
```